# SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory.setAdviceChain: can MethodInterceptor accept POJO that parameterizes @RabbitListener?

Tags: spring, spring-rabbit

Versions:

```
org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:2.4.8
openjdk version "11.0.12" 2021-07-20
```

XML:

```
  <bean id="myAdvice" class="com.acme.interceptors.TrackNewBarcode"/>
  <bean id="rmqMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.Jackson2JsonMessageConverter">
    <constructor-arg ref="myObjectMapper"/>
  </bean>
  <bean id="rabbitListenerContainerFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.config.SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory"/>
    <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="maxConcurrentConsumers" value="1"/>
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="316224000000"/>
    <property name="messageConverter" ref="rmqMessageConverter"/>
    <property name="adviceChain" ref="myAdvice"/>
  </bean>
```

Java:

```
package com.acme.tasks;

import com.acme.io.NewBarcodes;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;

@Validated
@Component
public class ConsumeBarcodes
{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumeBarcodes.class);

  @Value("${rabbitmq.queue}")
  private String queueName;

  public ConsumeBarcodes() {}

  @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queue}", ackMode = "AUTO")
  public void ingestNewBarcodes(@NotNull NewBarcodes newBarcodes)
  {
    logger.debug("RECEIVED message in ingestNewBarcodes from RabbitMQ queue: {}", queueName);
    // XXX Process newBarcodes here.
  }
}
```

Advice:

```
package com.acme.interceptors;

...

public class TrackNewBarcode implements MethodInterceptor
{
  ...
  @Override
  public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable
  {
    NewBarcodes newBarcodes = (NewBarcodes)methodInvocation.getArguments()[1];
    ...
  }
}
```

In the examples I have seen for `@RabbitListener` advices, in `invoke()`, argument #1 is cast to a `Message`.  But in my `@RabbitListener`, I rely on a Jackson message-converter to convert the inbound parameter into the POJO `NewBarcodes`.

QUESTION: in my advice here, can I cast argument #1 to the POJO `NewBarcodes`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is No.  `methodInvocation.getArguments()` returns a `Channel` in the first argument (index `0`), and a `Message` in the second argument (index `1`).  Casting a `Message` to `NewBarcodes` would lead to an exception.

Nevertheless, there are still other ways to encode an advice here.  I spell out one approach below.

First, per [Spring AOP docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.2.16.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aspectj-support), you should enable AOP functionality in your application configuration.  Eg:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class MyWebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer
{
  ...
}
```

Annotate `ConsumeBarcodes` with `@Aspect`, and set up `@Pointcut` and `@After` advice:

```
@Aspect
@Validated
@Component
public class ConsumeBarcodes
{
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConsumeBarcodes.class);

  @Value("${rabbitmq.queue}")
  private String queueName;

  public ConsumeBarcodes() {}

  @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbitmq.queue}", ackMode = "AUTO")
  public void ingestNewBarcodes(@NotNull NewBarcodes newBarcodes)
  {
    logger.debug("RECEIVED message in ingestNewBarcodes from RabbitMQ queue: {}", queueName);
    // XXX Process newBarcodes here.
  }

  @Pointcut("execution(com.acme.tasks.ConsumeBarcodes.ingestNewBarcodes(..)")
  public void newBarcodesIn() {}

  @After("newBarcodesIn()")
  public void ackNewBarcodesIn(JoinPoint jp)
  {
    NewBarcodes newBarcodes = (NewBarcodes)jp.getArgs()[0];
    ...
  }
}
```

Arguably, this is overkill, as we could simply put logic from `ackNewBarcodesIn()` inside `ingestNewBarcodes()` and forgo advices altogether.  Nevertheless, I have confirmed this setup works and the `@After` advice fires as expected.